# Using Sub-queries with comparison - Oracle

Tags: sql, subquery, oracle10g

I've been trying to manipulate a result into these three queries and I don't know what's wrong that I'm doing

**List all academic members participating in less than three groups.**

**List the academic ID leading the maximum number of groups**

with this query ( for the first part )

```
SELECT a.ID  , min(a.name) as Name  
FROM Academic a , researchGroup r 
WHERE count(r.managerID)>3
GROUP BY a.ID;
```

but It doesn't seem to work .

I have this relational schema

```
researchGroup(name (P.R Key Composite) , codeD , mainResearchArea , managerID /* forgien key with AcademicStaff(ID) */ , labID (P.R Key Composite) )

AcademicStaff(ID {PR KEY} , name)
```

any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you a list of academics and the number of research groups managed:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ac.ID                   AS academic_id
            ,MAX(ac.name)           AS academic_name
            ,COUNT(rg.managerID)    AS num_groups_managed
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(rg.managerID) DESC) AS academic_rank

        FROM 
            Academic AS ac

        INNER JOIN
            researchGroup AS rg
            ON (rg.managerID = ac.ID)

        GROUP BY 
            ac.ID

    ) AS subquery

WHERE
    --** uncomment the following line for the academics managing above 3 groups
    --num_groups_managed >= 3

    --** or uncomment the following line for the top-ranked academics (there could be more than 1)
    --academic_rank = 1

ORDER BY
    academic_rank ASC
    ,academic_name ASC
```

Uncommenting the relevant part of the WHERE clause will give you the results that you want.

Incidentally, it's a while since I've used Oracle SQL, so excuse any small syntax errors (in particular, I can't remember whether Oracle accepts the keyword `AS` after the table name).

Comment: This has pretty much solved the issue with few adjustments .. thank you very much !! .